# nbviewer 400: Bad Request, Error reading JSON notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to render my jupyter [notebook](https://github.com/vyaduvanshi/ds-projects/blob/master/coronavirus-future-prediction/coronavirus-future-prediction.ipynb) on [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) so I can share it with people. (The github render is not proper as you can see on the github link).

But trying to do so returns this error:

> 400 : Bad Request
>
> Error reading JSON notebook

[image]

I already tried the answers [on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744286/hosting-ipython-notebooks-on-github), they don't seem to change anything. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation has somehow resolved itself. Adding this here in case someone faces the same problem, maybe just try waiting.